Slightly higher voltage on a charger
I have a Dell Inspirion 5509 which has a barrel type charging port supporting 65w at 19.5v & 3.34 amps. It has a type C power delivery port.
I was having some issues with the barrel type charger so I bought a 65w Type C charger with PowerDelivery. While charging the charger gets heated up slightly
Can I use the Type C charger ? And is there risk of shorting something on my laptop if I use it ? or I must use the original one ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's normal for chargers to increase slightly in temperature during charging, as converting AC to DC (or inverting DC to AC) causes heat to be generated and dissipated. If a charger is getting more than slightly warm, and is unobstructed to air, that could be a cause for concern; however, if a charger is getting hot, that would be a cause for concern.

All chargers (actually ALL electrical devices) heat up to some degree when in use, that is typical.  USB-C chargers negotiate with the host device to find the maximum voltage and amperage allowed by both.  Since you said the USB-C charger is charging your laptop, then you are fine.  The only downside might be the USB-C charger cant output as much power as the original charger and therefore, charge the laptop slower.

@SiddhantSanghoi if that answer works for you, you should mark is as accepted and vote it up ;)
